# Synfony2 - Create & Edit forms not persisting association

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, persistence

I'm a beginner and I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

I have a ManyToOne/OneToMany association, and I have added a field in the form type, but the handlerequest is not taking into account the association, neither in create, nor in edit.

How might I proceed to save my associations ?

Here's my video controller

```
<?php

class VideoController extends Controller
{

... 

/**
 * Creates a new Video entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="video_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $video = new Video();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\VideoType', $video);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($video);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('video_show', array('id' => $video->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('video/new.html.twig', array(
        'video' => $video,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Video entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="video_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Video $video)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($video);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\VideoType', $video);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($video);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('video_edit', array('id' => $video->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('video/edit.html.twig', array(
        'video' => $video,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
...

}
```

Now the JT Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * JT
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="j_t")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\JTRepository")
 */
class JT
{

 ...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Video", mappedBy="jT")
 */
private $videos;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add videos
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos
 * @return JT
 */
public function addVideo(\AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos)
{
    $this->videos[] = $videos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove videos
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos
 */
public function removeVideo(\AppBundle\Entity\Video $videos)
{
    $this->videos->removeElement($videos);
}

/**
 * Get videos
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getVideos()
{
    return $this->videos;
}
}
```

The Video Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Video
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="video")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VideoRepository")
 */
class Video
{
    ....

          /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JT", inversedBy="videos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="jT_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $jT;



    /**
     * Set jT
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\JT $jT
     * @return Video
     */
    public function setJT(\AppBundle\Entity\JT $jT = null)
    {
        $this->jT = $jT;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get jT
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\JT
     */
    public function getJT()
    {
        return $this->jT;
    }


    /**
     * toString
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getTitle();
    }
}
```

And finally, the VideoType Form

```
class VideoType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ...

        ->add('jT','entity'
                       ,array("label"=>"JT",
                              'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
                              'class' => 'AppBundle:JT',
                              "attr"=>array("class"=>"form-control")
                      )
              );



}
```

I'd like to be able to chose if the "video" belongs to a "jT", and which one, from the video forms.

PS: How might I add a "none" option in the Entity input in the form ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

-- Explicitly save the jT Entity

```
$jT = $video->getJT();
$jT->addVideo($video);
$em->persist($jT);
$em->persist($video);
$em->flush();
```

-- Configure your entities for cascade persist

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JT", inversedBy="videos", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="jT_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $jT;

public function setJT(JT $jT)
{
   $this->jT = $jT;

   $jT->addVideo($this)

   return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Video", mappedBy="jT", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $videos;
```

Doctrine description for the latter: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods

Comment: Thank your for your reply !

Were I to use the first solution, how would I proceed, in the case of an edit, where I'd change the jT ?
Surely, I would have to have access to the _$oldJT_ entity, and do something along the lines of
    $oldJT->removeVideo($video);
How can I access  _$oldJT_ ? Can the following work ?
    $oldJT = $video->getJT();


Were I to opt for the second solution, would the following code suffice ?
    public function setJT(JT $jT)
    {
       $this->jT->removeVideo($this);
       $this->jT = $jT;
       $jT->addVideo($this)
       return $this;
    }